# What happens when level translator input and output are shorted?

Tags: short-circuit, level-shifting, buffer, level-translation

I am using a level translator in my design to interface between two systems. I also want an option to bypass the level translator by shorting a jumper resistor placed across terminals A and B.

What happens when I place the jumper when the level translator is assembled? Is it advisable to use it that way or do I have to keep the level translator as DNP when the jumper is placed? The translator I am using is the SN74AVC1T45.

Comment: You'll have two things driving the same line, that's not a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

If you have either Vcc at GND, the chip the outputs are [guaranteed](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74avc1t45.pdf?ts=1626590420523) to be in high-Z mode and you can have jumpers across it. I suggest a pull-down resistor and a jumper to Vcc.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will consider using a pull-down resistor and a jumper to Vcc. I think this will solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Pull-down only level converters like [NXP AN10441](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/AN10441.pdf) can be bypassed in such a way,

but a level converter that contains a gain stage and has no tri=state (High-Z) option is not going to play nicely with output connected to input.

I'd look for a way to overlap your jumper with the outline of the SN74AVC1T45 so that only one of them can be placed at a time. there appears to be room for an 0805 (or smaller) resistor (or jumper) between pads 3 and 4

Comment: I will consider this in my next design as I am using the DSBGA package currently and I cannot remove the IC every time I want to bypass the level translator.